# True or False?( Calculus)

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

If $F(x)$ is a continuous function in $[0,1]$ and $F(x) = 1$ for all rational numbers then $F(1/\sqrt2) = 1$. (True/ False)

I think the statement is true because since $F$ is continuous and $1/\sqrt2$ is in neighbourhood of some rational number so $F(1/\sqrt2)$ should be one so that limit can exist. Is this reason valid to prove the statement true.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, yes. (Sorry I can't only type one 'yes')

Comment: @SeewooLee try `Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$`

Comment: Yes, you thinking is correct.  You can improve your wording.  "so F(1/2–√) should be one so that limit can exist" is badly worded and semantically ... weird. But I know what you are trying to express and it is absolutely correct.

Comment: Joel Pereira's answer is a very nice mathematical way to express your thinking.

Comment: "$1/\sqrt{2}$ is in neighborhood of some rational number" is not what you want to be saying. The idea you want to convey is "every neighborhood of $1/\sqrt{2}$ contains a rational number", which is what @Joel Pereira does more precisely in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

For every $n$, there exists a rational number $q_n$ such that $\mid \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-q_n\mid < \frac{1}{n}$. So $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}q_n$ =  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Since F is continuous, 1 = $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$F($q_n$) = F($\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$) .

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true, although I would express it: there is a sequence $\{r_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of rational numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ such that $r_n \to 1/\sqrt{2}$, hence by continuity
$$
F(1/\sqrt{2}) = 
F(\lim_{n\to\infty} r_n) =
\lim_{n\to\infty} F(r_n) = 
\lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1 \,.
$$